# Javascript performance: Attaching variables to cached dom element vs attaching id calling by id

Tags: javascript, performance

lets say we have a requirement wherein an element can be present in several states.

```
var a = documentCreateElement('a');
```

To check the element **a** is in which state and keep a log of active state, I have this object:

```
var state = {
    all_states = ['State 1', 'State 2', 'State 3'],
    active = 'State 2'
}
```

Which process will be more resource intensive?

- A : Attaching an ID to **a** and checking the states in **state** object? And modifying the element (lets say change *href* of **a**) by calling it by ID.

  - B : OR, the element a is already cached in **a**, attaching the object directly to **a**, hence avoiding recaching the element all together.

eg of choice B:

```
a.state = state;
// Check state by checking a.state.active
```

Comment: Try it: http://jsperf.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would bet a lot that the cached version is faster because parsing a complex document can be expensive and you keep a pointer to the js object. But, to be sure you'd have to test it. Be sure use an html document of equivalent complexity to what you intend to publish.

Comment: I ran a test case with a large amount of elements (~40) and the cached version (choice B) performed much better. By almost a factor of 40. Thanks!